# Data Refresh Account - Login Failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer

Tags: 2010, security, reporting-services, powerpivot, secure-store

I am trying to configure my Unattended Data Refresh Account and continue to get the following error with the account I am using:

> The data refresh for 'sqltestrefresh.xlsx' on Report Center -
>   QA has failed with the following error:
>
> **Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type
>   at this computer**
>
> The data refresh has had 1 consecutive failures. If there are 10
>   consecutive failures we will disable the schedule. The service
>   application setting 'Disable data refresh due to consecutive failures'
>   enforces this behavior.
>
> The data refresh management page for this file can be used to view the
>   full history, and to take actions such as modifying the schedule to
>   exclude this data source from future refreshes.

I am at a loss for what else could be the issue. Here is what I have done to date.

1. I have setup the unattended account via the secure store service to use my credentials and the refresh works.
2. I have verified that the account I am trying to set up has access to the site collection where the data refresh is occurring.
3. I have tried to directly enter the credentials on the schedule data refresh page section for "Connect using the following Windows user credentials" and gotten the error, "**The provided credentials are invalid**". At which point I verified that the credentials are in fact valid.
4. I have verified the user has permissions to access the data source.

So do I need to give the account any login permissions on the server, or could this be a result of the account being in a Different OU in active directory?

Comment: how you entering credentials...domian\username?